# Typescript JSON to Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, internationalization

I'm trying to create an Array with a Key and a Value from a JSON. I'm working with i18n-iso-countries lib. I have got in a variable all countries from the countries lib in this JSON format:

```
{
  AD: "Andorra",
  AE: "United Arab Emirates",
  AF: "Afghanistan",
  AG: "Antigua and Barbuda",
  etc...
}
```

But in JSON format.

I know I can transform the JSON into an object with `Object.values(countries)`, but doing it like this, the `Key` is lost and I get this format:

```
{
  0: "Afghanistan"
  1: "Albania"
  2: "Algeria"
  3: "American Samoa"
}
```

All I want is a new Array like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 'AD'
    country: 'Andorra'
  },
  {
    id: 'AE'
    country: 'United Arab Emirates'
  }
]
```

etc...

I suppose it is something to do with forEach my countries and add id as Key and country as Value, but I can't resolve it.

Thanks!

Comment: `Object.entries(json).map(  ([key, value]) => ({id:key, country: value})  )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.entries() to get an array of key-value pairs from an object:

```js
const countries = {
  AD: "Andorra",
  AE: "United Arab Emirates",
  AF: "Afghanistan",
  AG: "Antigua and Barbuda"
}

const countriesArray = Object.entries(countries).map(([id, country]) => ({ id, country }))

console.log(countriesArray)
```

Comment: How is this related to typescript?

Comment: Cause I'm using TypeScript?